# Rotated image for WCS GetCoverage Operation "v1.1.0" in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, geotiff-tiff, wcs, getcoverage

I am using GeoServer v2.10.1. I have created a layer for testing using "Geo-tiff" store and later published it that computed "Native and Declared" Coordinate reference systems and computed "Bounding Boxes" automatically from image raster/data.

[image: CRS and Bounding Box for Layer]

After creating layer I called WCS GetCapabilities operation and found my layer/coverage in available coverage. Next I have tried calling WCS DescribeCoverage Operation and found that the coordinates under Bounding Box are rotated as shown in figure.

[image: DescribeCoverage Operation]

For the confirmation I tried GetCoverage Operation on same coverage and the image downloaded was also rotated.

> GetCoverage&identifier=coveragename&BOUNDINGBOX=-92.37604305953325,19.9981422668471,-74.48971252207147,29.99999999730591,urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84&FORMAT=image/tiff&store=true

So is this default WCS behaviour?

As I have tried the same layer using WMS (in OpenLayers) and get the correct image.

Comment: Perhaps there is a bug in GeoServer 2.10. Could you write a mail to GeoServer users mailing list and ask? You can use demo layer for test request http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?service=WCS&version=1.1.1&request=describecoverage&identifiers=nurc:Img_Sample. I believe that GridBaseCRS in EPSG:4326 should have coordinates also in latitude-longitude order like they are for EPSG:4326 BoundingBox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "rotation", what you are seeing is an axis flip, read more about it here:
https://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Axis_Order_Confusion

Long story short, the UI reports data in lon/lat order, but the recent versions of OGC protocols demand the axis order to be lat/lon instead, that's why you see the "inconsistency".